# Top bar is dimmed out after reopening app

Tags: java, android

This doesn't happen every time, but sometimes if I open the app then exit but not kill it and after some time reopen it, the status bar get's dimmed out.

**This is how it should be looking:**

[image]

**And this is how it looks after the weird behaviour:**

[image]

I also found out, that this happens when I make a change to my code and hit Instant Run instead of simple Run. In this case,the bug is happening every time.

I don't know how to solve this. If you have any ideas where to search or how can I move to figure this out, I would appreciate it.

Comment: As documentation below this - "You can control the behaviors and visibility of the action bar with the ActionBar APIs, which were added in Android 3.0 (API level 11)."

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer. Inside the main Activity that draws the top bar, I used the onResume() function to draw again the top bar when the app is onPause().